# Pretty Printing Arbitrarily Nested Dictionaries & Lists in Vim

Tags: json, list, dictionary, vim, pretty-print

I've run into several scenarios where I lists & dictionaries of data in vim, with arbitrarily nested data structures, i.e.:

```
a = [ 'somedata', d : { 'one': 'x', 'two': 'y', 'three': 'z' }, 'moredata' ]
b = { 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ] }
```

I'd really like to have a way to 'pretty print' them in a tabular format. It would be especially helpful to simply treat them as JSON directly in vim. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give an example of desired output please? Please note that your first example, the `a` variable, is not a valid structure in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at Tim Pope's [Scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) which provides many niceties for vim scripting and plugin development.

Although I am not sure how pretty `:PP` is I have found it pretty enough for my uses.

It should also be noted that vim script dictionaries and arrays are very similar to JSON, so you could in theory use any JSON tools after some clean up.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is valid json, you can turn to the external `python -m json.tool`

so, you just execute in vim: `%!python -m json.tool`.

Unfortunately your example won't work, if you take a valid json example with nested dict/lists:

[image]

### Note

that in the screencast I have `ft=json`, so some quotes cannot be seen in normal mode, the text I used:

```
[{"test1": 1, "test2": "win", "t3":{"nest1":"foo","nest2":"bar"}}, {"test1": 1, "test2": "win", "t3":{"nest1":"foo","nest2":"bar"}}, {"test1": 1, "test2": "win", "t3":{"nest1":"foo","nest2":"bar"}}, {"test1": 1, "test2": "win", "t3":{"nest1":"foo","nest2":"bar"}}]
```

Comment: Post your `vimrc.bundle` and `vimrc` please.

Comment: @Aftnix my current vimrc has about 1000 lines, and it is growing... So I won't post here. you can check by yourself, if you like : https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc